# Export schema for a view in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do I export the schema for a database view in SQL Developer? Not the `CREATE` statement, but the effective list of fields and types? Like:

```
FIELD         | TYPE
---------------------------------
id            | integer
name          | varchar2(255)
```

Comment: your question isn't clear. you want an export, but not a DDL export. You want a data dictionary report? Like this? http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/generating-html-data-dictionary-reports-with-oracle-sql-developer/

Comment: Or maybe you just want a query that gives you the equivalent of doing `describe <view>`? It really isn't clear what you mean by `export`. (The schema is the owner of the view, incidentally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a new script window in SQL Developer, connect, then execute this:

```
describe VIEWNAME;
```

It will return a table with three columns "Name", "Null", and "Type". It works for views as well as for tables.